# jquery wordpress undesired behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I don't how to solve the next problem:

When page loads, I am using jquery to search for a class and then to automatically put that "link" to the desired website, but I am missing something... Because when a user choose first image from the portfolio (art gallery) all other images in there have that link.

Here is the actual code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(".row a, .grid-image").click(function( event ) {
       window.setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery(".preview").each(function(){
                var a = jQuery(jQuery(this).children("a")[0]);
                var galleryLink = false;
                if(jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.gallery-link')[0]){
                    galleryLink = jQuery(jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.gallery-link')[0]);
                }

                if(!galleryLink){
                    a.click(function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }else{
                    a.attr("href", jQuery('.gallery-link').attr("href"));
                    a.attr("target", "_blank");
                }

            });
       }, 100); 
    });
});
```

Just to recap:

1. User loads the gallery and clicks on any image there
2. That image is zoomed in and has some text on the left side

   example:

   title: image title 1

   description: some text here

   link: link to the author (which has .gallery-link class )
3. if there is a link to the author's work
4. then that link is added to title of the image (in this case "image title 1") above description text and that title automatically becomes clickable

Problem:

When page is loaded and user choose one image from gallery, that image is zoomed and "image title 1" links to "link to author 1", but when user close that zoomed image and choose "image title 2" links to  "link to the author 1" (which is wrong) and from that point on, it doesn't work as I want, for any "image title" links to "link to the author 1"...

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML markup that you're using? I'm just curious to know where your `preview` class is located. Thanks.

Comment: yes change `click` to the `on` method. The .click method is added to existing elements, on allows for the creation of new elements with the event handler attached.

Comment: @KamranKhan http://jsfiddle.net/ro7tc7o8/ that is a structure

Comment: @David When I replace first occurrence of `click` to `on` it doesn't work at all, and I think you were referring to second one, right? That didn't help either...

Comment: `on` has a different structure `jQuery(document).on('click','your selectors', function(){});`

Comment: @David I tried what you have suggested and it doesn't work, maybe you should write what exactly should I change or something... Thank you.

Comment: Hey Morhpeus, it would be helpful to provide the HTML where the function is being called from i.e. where your `.row` markup is in the document as well.

Comment: provide your html and ill have a look at it. I was referring to just having one click handler, i dont know your html structure so i cant see what 'a' is etc...

Comment: I have found what was wrong: I've forgot to change `a.attr("href", jQuery('.gallery-link').attr("href"));` to `a.attr("href", galleryLink);`  Thank you for your efforts.